Bash not using PATH defined in PATH if I use any other number in head -n than 1
This is a little funny one, at least to me. I have a file on which I am running awk and cut command in a loop being fed by head command. The command is:
head -n X all.du.K.txt | while read line ; do NON_APP=$(echo ${line} | awk '{print $1}' | cut -d"," -f2) ; APP=$(echo ${line} | awk '{print $2}' | cut -d"," -f2) ; PATH=$(echo ${line} | awk '{print $3}') ; echo ${PATH},${NON_APP},${APP} ; done >> final.csv
If X is 1, it works, but if X is 2 or any other number, I get the following error:

head -n 2 all.du.K.txt | while read line ; do NON_APP=$(echo ${line} | awk '{print $1}' | cut -d"," -f2) ; APP=$(echo ${line} | awk '{print $2}' | cut -d"," -f2) ; PATH=$(echo ${line} | awk '{print $3}') ; echo ${PATH},${NON_APP},${APP} ; done >> final.csv
Command 'cut' is available in the following places

/bin/cut
/usr/bin/cut
The command could not be located because '/bin:/usr/bin' is not included in the PATH environment variable.
cut: command not found
Command 'awk' is available in the following places
/bin/awk
/usr/bin/awk
The command could not be located because '/bin:/usr/bin' is not included in the PATH environment variable.
awk: command not found
Command 'awk' is available in the following places
/bin/awk
/usr/bin/awk
The command could not be located because '/usr/bin:/bin' is not included in the PATH environment variable.
awk: command not found
Command 'cut' is available in the following places
/bin/cut
/usr/bin/cut
The command could not be located because '/usr/bin:/bin' is not included in the PATH environment variable.
cut: command not found
Command 'awk' is available in the following places
/bin/awk
/usr/bin/awk
The command could not be located because '/usr/bin:/bin' is not included in the PATH environment variable.
awk: command not found


My $PATH env is as follows:
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin
If run the above loop with set -x on, I get the following output, just for your all's reference:


head -n 2 all.du.K.txt
read line
++ echo /var/opt/gitlab/gitlab-rails/shared/artifacts/e0/e7/e0e72896f2d07d134de6efb2d6541bed7e297e17f010f67f30247abc56d92c6c,5375K /var/opt/gitlab/gitlab-rails/shared/artifacts/e0/e7/e0e72896f2d07d134de6efb2d6541bed7e297e17f010f67f30247abc56d92c6c,17086K /var/opt/gitlab/gitlab-rails/shared/artifacts/e0/e7/e0e72896f2d07d134de6efb2d6541bed7e297e17f010f67f30247abc56d92c6c
++ awk '{print $1}'
++ cut -d, -f2
NON_APP=5375K
++ echo /var/opt/gitlab/gitlab-rails/shared/artifacts/e0/e7/e0e72896f2d07d134de6efb2d6541bed7e297e17f010f67f30247abc56d92c6c,5375K /var/opt/gitlab/gitlab-rails/shared/artifacts/e0/e7/e0e72896f2d07d134de6efb2d6541bed7e297e17f010f67f30247abc56d92c6c,17086K /var/opt/gitlab/gitlab-rails/shared/artifacts/e0/e7/e0e72896f2d07d134de6efb2d6541bed7e297e17f010f67f30247abc56d92c6c
++ awk '{print $2}'
++ cut -d, -f2
APP=17086K
++ echo /var/opt/gitlab/gitlab-rails/shared/artifacts/e0/e7/e0e72896f2d07d134de6efb2d6541bed7e297e17f010f67f30247abc56d92c6c,5375K /var/opt/gitlab/gitlab-rails/shared/artifacts/e0/e7/e0e72896f2d07d134de6efb2d6541bed7e297e17f010f67f30247abc56d92c6c,17086K /var/opt/gitlab/gitlab-rails/shared/artifacts/e0/e7/e0e72896f2d07d134de6efb2d6541bed7e297e17f010f67f30247abc56d92c6c
++ awk '{print $3}'
PATH=/var/opt/gitlab/gitlab-rails/shared/artifacts/e0/e7/e0e72896f2d07d134de6efb2d6541bed7e297e17f010f67f30247abc56d92c6c
echo /var/opt/gitlab/gitlab-rails/shared/artifacts/e0/e7/e0e72896f2d07d134de6efb2d6541bed7e297e17f010f67f30247abc56d92c6c,5375K,17086K
read line
++ echo /var/opt/gitlab/gitlab-rails/shared/artifacts/e0/38/e03865e0382175da3126eb126534c2d3c9b4cf69483fa8a167d05c070360edc4,145K /var/opt/gitlab/gitlab-rails/shared/artifacts/e0/38/e03865e0382175da3126eb126534c2d3c9b4cf69483fa8a167d05c070360edc4,191K /var/opt/gitlab/gitlab-rails/shared/artifacts/e0/38/e03865e0382175da3126eb126534c2d3c9b4cf69483fa8a167d05c070360edc4
++ awk '{print $1}'
++ '[' -x /usr/lib/command-not-found ']'
++ cut -d, -f2
++ /usr/lib/command-not-found -- awk
++ '[' -x /usr/lib/command-not-found ']'
++ /usr/lib/command-not-found -- cut
Command 'cut' is available in the following places


/bin/cut
/usr/bin/cut
The command could not be located because '/usr/bin:/bin' is not included in the PATH environment variable.
cut: command not found
Command 'awk' is available in the following places
/bin/awk
/usr/bin/awk
The command could not be located because '/usr/bin:/bin' is not included in the PATH environment variable.
awk: command not found
++ return 127
++ return 127


NON_APP=
++ echo /var/opt/gitlab/gitlab-rails/shared/artifacts/e0/38/e03865e0382175da3126eb126534c2d3c9b4cf69483fa8a167d05c070360edc4,145K /var/opt/gitlab/gitlab-rails/shared/artifacts/e0/38/e03865e0382175da3126eb126534c2d3c9b4cf69483fa8a167d05c070360edc4,191K /var/opt/gitlab/gitlab-rails/shared/artifacts/e0/38/e03865e0382175da3126eb126534c2d3c9b4cf69483fa8a167d05c070360edc4
++ awk '{print $2}'
++ '[' -x /usr/lib/command-not-found ']'
++ /usr/lib/command-not-found -- awk
++ cut -d, -f2
++ '[' -x /usr/lib/command-not-found ']'
++ /usr/lib/command-not-found -- cut
Command 'cut' is available in the following places


/bin/cut
/usr/bin/cut
The command could not be located because '/bin:/usr/bin' is not included in the PATH environment variable.
cut: command not found
Command 'awk' is available in the following places
/bin/awk
/usr/bin/awk
The command could not be located because '/usr/bin:/bin' is not included in the PATH environment variable.
awk: command not found
++ return 127
++ return 127


APP=
++ echo /var/opt/gitlab/gitlab-rails/shared/artifacts/e0/38/e03865e0382175da3126eb126534c2d3c9b4cf69483fa8a167d05c070360edc4,145K /var/opt/gitlab/gitlab-rails/shared/artifacts/e0/38/e03865e0382175da3126eb126534c2d3c9b4cf69483fa8a167d05c070360edc4,191K /var/opt/gitlab/gitlab-rails/shared/artifacts/e0/38/e03865e0382175da3126eb126534c2d3c9b4cf69483fa8a167d05c070360edc4
++ awk '{print $3}'
++ '[' -x /usr/lib/command-not-found ']'
++ /usr/lib/command-not-found -- awk
Command 'awk' is available in the following places


/bin/awk
/usr/bin/awk
The command could not be located because '/usr/bin:/bin' is not included in the PATH environment variable.
awk: command not found
++ return 127


PATH=
echo ,,
read line


Sample from my input file:
/var/opt/gitlab/gitlab-rails/shared/artifacts/e0/e7/e0e72896f2d07d134de6efb2d6541bed7e297e17f010f67f30247abc56d92c6c,5375K  /var/opt/gitlab/gitlab-rails/shared/artifacts/e0/e7/e0e72896f2d07d134de6efb2d6541bed7e297e17f010f67f30247abc56d92c6c,17086K /var/opt/gitlab/gitlab-rails/shared/artifacts/e0/e7/e0e72896f2d07d134de6efb2d6541bed7e297e17f010f67f30247abc56d92c6c
/var/opt/gitlab/gitlab-rails/shared/artifacts/e0/38/e03865e0382175da3126eb126534c2d3c9b4cf69483fa8a167d05c070360edc4,145K   /var/opt/gitlab/gitlab-rails/shared/artifacts/e0/38/e03865e0382175da3126eb126534c2d3c9b4cf69483fa8a167d05c070360edc4,191K   /var/opt/gitlab/gitlab-rails/shared/artifacts/e0/38/e03865e0382175da3126eb126534c2d3c9b4cf69483fa8a167d05c070360edc4
/var/opt/gitlab/gitlab-rails/shared/artifacts/e0/f2/e0f23d7875aff9c6b4ef20f27e7d38c4e312811ae627319267f566a4dc244636,168K   /var/opt/gitlab/gitlab-rails/shared/artifacts/e0/f2/e0f23d7875aff9c6b4ef20f27e7d38c4e312811ae627319267f566a4dc244636,555K   /var/opt/gitlab/gitlab-rails/shared/artifacts/e0/f2/e0f23d7875aff9c6b4ef20f27e7d38c4e312811ae627319267f566a4dc244636
Any idea what the Fun is happening here? Bash version is "GNU bash, version 5.0.17(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)"

BTW you don't need all those awk's and cut's; shell can do the whole job more simply head ... | while read non app name; do echo ${non#*,},${app#*,},$name; done >outfile

You're overwriting $PATH in a loop:
PATH=$(echo ${line} | awk '{print $3}')

You should use a different name for this variable, for example APP_PATH.

Ahh, awesomely stupid of me. Thanks for pointing out.
